# What does this pattern (?<=\w)\W+(?=\w) mean in a Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

What does this pattern  `(?<=\w)\W+(?=\w)`  mean in a Python regular expression?

```
#l is a list 
print(re.sub("(?<=\w)\W+(?=\w)", " ", l))
```

Comment: Are you *sure* `l` is a list? If so, that call can't possibly work. The third argument to `re.sub` is supposed to be a single string, which is what the substitution works on.

Comment: yes, it is a string. I was wrong. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of the elements:

- `\w` means an alphanumeric character
- `\W+` is the opposite of `\w`; with the `+` it means one or more non-alphanumeric characters
- `?<=` is called a "lookbehind assertion"
- `?=` is a "lookahead assertion"

So this `re.sub` statement means "if there are one or more non-alphanumeric characters with an alphanumeric character before and after, replace the non-alphanumeric character(s) with a space".

And by the way, the third argument to `re.sub` must be a string (or bytes-like object); it can't be a list.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. yes, it is a string, I was wrong. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just put it into a site like regex101.com and hover the cursor over the parts.

- https://regex101.com/r/JtrWIw/1

It would match non-word chars between word chars.  Bits between the last 'd' of 'word' and the first 'w' of 'word' from the string below as an example...

```
word^&*((*&^%$%^&*& ^%$£%^&**&^%$£!"£$%^&*()word
```

**Example:**

```
import re

#if it is a list...
l = ['John Smith', 'This%^&*(string', 'Never!£$Mind^&*I$?/Solved{}][]It']

#l is a list 
print(re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\W+(?=\w)", " ", l[2]))

Never Mind I Solved It
```